# How do I shutdown Slitaz from terminal?

Tags: linux, shutdown

I have Slitaz installed on my home server and the only way of interfacing with it is through and SSH connection. I have tried

```
shutdown -h now
```

But it only tells me shutdown is not a command

So I tried

```
init 0
```

Then it just sat there not doing anything? Shutdown is also not in the package manager.

How can I turn it off without resulting to the pulling of the power cord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **halt** to stop the system.

**[Turn off the system or restart](http://www.slitaz.org/en/doc/handbook/cmdline.html)**

> To stop or restart SliTaz, you can use
>   the halt or reboot commands or the
>    key combination
>   which enables a system reboot. In case
>   of any problems you can use the -f
>   option signifing forced:

```
 # halt
 To restart :
 # reboot
 Or :
 # reboot -f
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `shutdown` command in SliTaz, so you'll have to use `halt` and family. But by default `halt` command doesn't do ACPI off. To get complete shut down instead of hanging on "System halted" message, you can use

```
poweroff
```

Note that using `halt -p`, which is normally a synonym of `poweroff`, won't work because BusyBox doesn't understand this option.

Answer (score -1):

use this command

```
shutdown -r now
```

or see this : [LinuxShutdown](http://www.roseindia.net/linux/linux-basics/LinuxShutDown.shtml)

Comment: root@Albuquerque:~# shutdown
-sh: shutdown: not found

Comment: see link that i set